# Unable to grant previledges to MYSQL_USER priviledges in docker automatically without manual steps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mysql-5.7

I want to grant all the privileges to user defined in environment variable of MYSQL_USER with MYSQL_PASSWORD.

TRIED:
1. (WORKED)I wrote an sql script to grant permission to add it to the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and it worked. But for each new user i have to edit not only the environment variable but also the sql script which is not feasible for me.
2. (WORKED)Get inside the container and grant the privileges. (Manual Work)

EXPECTING:
Pass new MYSQL_USER name only at the docker-compose.yml file in environment variable and when the container is up it automically grant all the privileges without having the do anything manually.

DOCKER COMPOSE FILE

```
services:

  dbserver:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dockerdb123
      MYSQL_USER: user
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./datadir/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (<- without passing the grant script here)
```

Access denied for user ''@'172.20.0.1' (using password: YES)

THERE ARE ANSWER TO THIS BUT NONE ARE AUTOMATIC THERE ARE MANUAL STEPS.

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing the varible  `MYSQL_PASSWORD` , in the docs of the docker hub image it says that `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` goes for user root, so i think you need to change yml like this :

```
  dbserver:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dockerdb123
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
```

and then it will connect and it gets the superuser.
it seems like your trying root pass on user named user- so it wont work.

docs:

```
MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
These variables are optional,
used in conjunction to create a new user and to set that user's password. This user will be granted superuser permissions (see above) for the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable. Both variables are required for a user to be created.
Do note that there is no need to use this mechanism to create the root superuser, that user gets created by default with the password specified by the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable.
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't word. Again getting Access denied for that user.

Comment: so try to connect with root user and the password in `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` see if it connects, if so then run in psql this command : `\du+`    it will show you all the users and grants. also if you changed somthing in yml file you shold do `docker-compose stop` and then up as changes will not applay without it.